# Interacting with deployed Ethereum/Quorum contract

Tags: ethereum, web3js, quorum

I'm trying to deploy a contract in a private Ethereum (Quorum with RAFT but executing only public tx) using `solc version 0.5.1` and `web3 version 1.0.0-beta.36`. `Number` contract is deployed and `contractAddress` is returned upon receiving `receipt`.

Though might seem cumbersome, for easier reproducibility, I've written all code here. The problem I'm having is in the last block (interacting with contract).

```
const solc = require('solc');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        solContract: {
            content: `
            pragma solidity ^0.5.1;
            contract Number {
                uint private num = 100;
                function getNum() public view returns(uint) {
                    return num;
                }
                function setNum(uint _num) public returns(bool success) {
                    num = _num;
                    return true;
                }
            }`
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['*']
            }
        }
    }
}

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)))
const abi = output.contracts.solContract.Number.abi
const bytecode = `0x${output.contracts.solContract.Number.evm.bytecode.object}`

const web3 = new Web3('http://127.0.0.1:8555');
const privateKey = '0x82f74b773d7f948153d7eb8c192bd9819e3e94073d8bdc0e03d659aa42cd34ba';
// const account = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(privateKey);

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi);

web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount('0x27f4cD26d7e4eAde2052ec5B61f6594D1481C4A2', 'passwordstring', 600)
    .then(
        contract.deploy({
            data: bytecode,
            arguments: []
        })
            .send({
                from: '0x27f4cD26d7e4eAde2052ec5B61f6594D1481C4A2',
                gas: 0x47b760
            }, (error, transactionHash) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                } else if (transactionHash) {
                    web3.eth.getTransaction(transactionHash)
                        .then((data) => {
                            console.log(data)
                        })
                }
            })
            .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
                console.log(receipt.contractAddress)
            }))

// Interacting with deployed contract
// contract address returned from above
// 0x101ea6703717Fa3CF70e96FD3C84FE74ddca50eB
contract.options.address = '0x101ea6703717Fa3CF70e96FD3C84FE74ddca50eB'

contract.methods.getNum().call({
    from: 0x27f4cD26d7e4eAde2052ec5B61f6594D1481C4A2,
    gas: 0x47b760
}, (err, data) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(data)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're having here is that when you execute the last block of code, the contract has actually not yet been deployed.

You need to perform the call to getNum() within the `on()` block, e.g.:

```js
            .on('receipt', (receipt) => {
                console.log("CONTRACT CREATED, ADDRESS = ", receipt.contractAddress)
                performGetNum(receipt.contractAddress)
            })
            
function performGetNum(contractAddress) {
    sampleContract.options.address = contractAddress
    sampleContract.methods.getNum().call({
        from: "0xed9d02e382b34818e88b88a309c7fe71e65f419d",
        gas: 0x47b760
    }, (err, data) => {
        err ? console.log(err) : console.log("getNum() returned value: ", data)
    })
}
```